Create Tasks with multiple Owners / Assignees
We have our Group Task feature activated which apparently allows us to create a new Task and select multiple Assignees, creating a separate Task for each user selected.
That's fine. But we only seem to have that from our main create New Task button on our Task tab. We would like to be able to do it from within a Lead. If we use a Task Lightning Quick Action it will only give us an Owner/Assignee field which allows one value, not allowing multiple users to be chosen.
What's the trick we're missing here ? Do we need to make a whole new button for a flow and make a new Task-based form pop up for the user to fill out ? If so, will we be able to have an Owner/Assignee field with multiple values ?

Did you ever find a solution to this? We are running into the exact same scenario, where we're invoking the Global action NewTask from a LWC, and can only assign it to one person.
